# iPhone photos app says storage is full but Settings says 20 gb avail

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

I have icloud with 200gb storage.  iCloud shows it has 30 gb available.  My iPhone photos app says "Update Paused.  Not Enough iPhone Storage".  There's a "Manage Storage" link, which brings you to the iPhone Settings>Storage.  There, it shows the phone has ~20gb of storage left.

I can take pics, backup appears to be working.  Can't figure out if I should be doing something or if this is a bug.
Thanks!

[image: iPhone Photos storage warning]

[image: iPhone settings]